# Google sheet app not rejecting invalid date validation input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have created an attendance system with a form to mark the attendance on google sheets. I have put a date validation wherein the user can only select today's and yesterday's date to mark the attendance. Data validation is rejecting invalid input in Desktop but not in the google sheets andriod app. User is able to enter the date outside of the dropdown options. Is this a bug or am I missing something here.

Here's the link to the sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jUrYdRCZR_IbqsmwKJeJQ9J1HcT_gFetDcLui4fllw0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: "This form can only be viewed by users in the owner's organization".

Comment: Hey! I've changed it to 
Anyone on the Internet with this link can edit

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jUrYdRCZR_IbqsmwKJeJQ9J1HcT_gFetDcLui4fllw0/edit#gid=1611147373

Comment: The validation is using a range in a sheet named "Validations" which doesn't seem to exist... Where is the list of available dates?

Comment: Hi. 'Validations' tab was hidden. Sorry. I've unhidden it now. You can go through it.

Comment: The function `TODAY` will change every day. Is your intention for the validation to also do that?

Comment: Yes. It needs to show only today's and yesterday's date.